# Чему эквивалентно на python s+=1/n?

Tags: python

```python
s=1
n=1
for i in range(1,4):
  s+=1/n
  n=n+2
  print(i,s,n)
```

Поясните, пожалуйста, чему эквивалентно `s+=1/n`?

Ожидала, что это последовательные операции `s=s+1`, `s=s/n`.
Но по факту отработки кода, выходит, что не так.

```
i  s                   n
1 2.0                  3
2 2.3333333333333335   5
3 2.5333333333333337   7
```

Answer (score 1):

`s += 1 / n` эквивалентно `s = s + 1 / n`. Порядок действий: сначала деление (`1 / n`), потом сложение.

Чтобы реализовать то, что вы задумали, нужно выполнить эти операции отдельно:

```python
s += 1
s /= n
```

Answer (score 1):

По сути `s += 1/n` Равнозначно `s = s + (1/n)`
Так что все правильно выводит.

```
s = 1  
s = 1 + (1/1) = 2  
s = 2 + (1/3) = 2.3333  
s = 2.333 + (1/5) = 2.5333
```